# Simple UDP Socket Tutorial Needed

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, udp

I have been searching and reading all day, and have not found a UDP sockets programming tutorial suitable for a newbie. I know UDPClient programming, but, because of the inability of UDPClient to receive a message without blocking AND without having problems with cross-thread commands, I have turned to sockets. I don't even truly know if what I am trying to do is possible, so please help in any way you can.
Much Obliged.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try these:

- [Socket Code Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx)
- [Testing TCP and UDP socket servers using C# and .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/testingsocketservers.aspx)
- [Simple UDP example code](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxnetcom/thread/92846ccb-fad3-469a-baf7-bb153ce2d82b)

Remember: [Google is your friend](http://www.google.com.br/search?q=udp+socket+sample+c%23+-java).

Comment: As I said, I have been Googling all day. I was hoping that people would have knowledge of secluded tutorials or something.

Comment: Last link seems very interesting (Simple UDP example code), take a look

Comment: It was quite acceptable. Thank you.

Comment: This is now the top result from Google when searching on the subject. So thank you Rubens for making it when easier to find. :)