# How to switch a ConnectionHandler to UDP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My ASP.Net Core application provides a TCP listener, implemented with a custom `ConnectionHandler`, to receive binary data from another process (let's call it `Datasource`) on another host. This data is then sent to the browser through a WebSocket (called `DataSink` in the code).

Since the process `Datasource` has changed from a single TCP connection to UDP datagrams, I need to adapt (its internals are out of my reach).

How can I switch the current implementation to an UDP listener? Is there a canonical way how this is done with ASP.Net Core?

```cs
public class MySpecialConnectionHandler : ConnectionHandler
{
    private readonly IMyDataSink DataSink;

    public MySpecialConnectionHandler(IMyDataSink dataSink)
    {
        DataSink = dataSink;
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync(ConnectionContext context)
    {
        TransportConnection connection = context as TransportConnection;

        Console.WriteLine("new connection: " + connection.RemoteAddress + ":" + connection.RemotePort);

        while (true)
        {
            var result = await connection.Transport.Input.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var buffer = result.Buffer;

            foreach (var segment in buffer)
            {
                await DataSink.RelayData(segment.Span.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            if (result.IsCompleted)
            {
                break;
            }

            connection.Transport.Input.AdvanceTo(buffer.End);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(connection.ConnectionId + " disconnected");
    }
}
```

The UDP listener must be available while the ASP.Net Core application is running.

**EDIT:**

Order and reliability of the datagram transmission is not that important (perhaps not at all), since the transmitted data is a MPEG1-stream multiplexed into MPEG-TS. The data source is on the first host, the ASP.Net Core application is on a second host and the receiver / consumer is a third host. The host creating the stream and the receiving process on the third host are in separate networks. The ASP.Net Core application acts as a relay. The sender is sending all time, but does not care about whether the data is received or not.

**EDIT 2:**

The main problem right now is where to put the UdpClient. The previous implementation (back when we used TCP) configured the Kestrel server for additional TCP listening and used the already presented `ConnectionHandler`:

```cs
return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .ConfigureKestrel((_, options) =>
    {
        // HTTP
        options.Listen(networkInterface, httpPort);

        // HTTPS
        options.Listen(networkInterface, httpsPort, builder => builder.UseHttps());

        // stream sink
        options.Listen(streamInterface, streamPort, builder => builder.UseConnectionHandler<MySpecialConnectionHandler >());
    });
```

The `ConnectionHandler` accepts the incoming TCP connection and then forwards the streaming data to a number of connected WebSockets. Since this is not usable with UDP datagrams, I need to place the UdpClient somewhere where it continuously (i.e. `while(true)`) receives datagrams and forwards them to the WebSockets. My problem is that I don't know where to put it, run the background thread and have the communication span threads without having any problems with this inter-thread data flow (like race conditions).

Comment: There is no one single way to do it. That depends highly on the protocol that's based on the UDP. Mind that you need to care for order and completeness yourself, since UDP is not reliable nor keeps order ( packets can arrive out of order or not at all). That means you need to implement requesting missing packets again and you need to implement packet sorting... You also need to figure out whether your "Datasource" is at all online, since UDP is also connection-less.

Comment: That said, I'd recommend you sit down with the Datasource-Team (or at least one of them) and have them explain the (application) protocol to you.

Comment: The application protocol is a simple video stream, so missing packages are no problem at all. Reliability of datagram transmission is not that important. Right now, I don't even know where to place a ``UdpListener`` at all.

Comment: Do you support multiple streams?

Comment: No, only one stream and only one watcher on the other end.

Comment: Ok, then it's at least possible. Without knowing your overall design, it's hard to help, though. Is your server just starting to spill out data at some random point in time or do you have to request for a stream to start?

Comment: It is not using RTSP over UDP by any chance? What is the encoding? MJPEG? Mpeg4 (H.264, ... ) , something else? Could be anything in a selected range?

Comment: @Fildor I've added some hopefully helpful information.

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7265307/982149

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the link, but I'm afraid the situation there is simpler than our situation and therefore slightly less comparable. I added some further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to conclude this:

We used a combination of a `BackgroundWorker` with an `UdpClient`. The `BackgroundWorker` is only instantiated when there is at least one receiver:

```
StreamReceiver = new BackgroundWorker();
StreamReceiver.DoWork += ReceiveStream;
StreamReceiver.RunWorkerAsync();
```

`ReceiveStream` is a private method that establishes the `UdpClient` and then waits for incoming data that needs to be relayed.

```
private async void ReceiveStream(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    // DataSinkPort is a const int
    UdpClient datasource = new UdpClient(_DataSinkPort);

    while (true)
    {
        var rec = await datasource.ReceiveAsync();
        await RelayData(rec.Buffer);

        if (_CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

The method `RelayData` just uses the outgoing TCP connection of each subscribed receiver.